# Select records for batch processing in loop

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to select the records in batch wise, like in below example we have 20 records. if I give batch of size of 10 there would be two loops. the problem here is if I do top 10 then 555 value will be split as its position is 10 and 11. hence 555 should also include in that top first batch. how I can achieve this? this is just example, I have 900 million records to process and my batch will be 2 million in real scenario.

```
ID
-------
111
111
111
222
222
333
333
444
444
555
555
666
666
777
777
888
888
```

Comment: Formatting tip: Edit your question. 1) Remove empty lines between data. 2) Mark the sample data, and click `{}`.

Comment: Pls provide expected output

Comment: Also show us your current code attempt.

Comment: A bit more context would help. What form do you need the split-up sets of ids in? Inside sql as a temp table for further joining? As part of a cursor loop to return rows in chunks to an app? Those are just a couple guesses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `top with ties` - this might return more records then stated but will not break similar ids to different batches:

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(ID int)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(111),(111),(111),
(222),(222),
(333),(333),
(444),(444),
(555),(555),
(666),(666),
(777),(777),
(888),(888)
```

The select statement:

```
SELECT TOP 10 WITH TIES ID
FROM @T 
ORDER BY ID
```

Results:

```
row     ID
1       111
2       111
3       111
4       222
5       222
6       333
7       333
8       444
9       444
10      555
11      555
```

Answer (score 0):

While selecting the records, you can group them by id prior to limiting their number.

Comment: Due to huge volume of data grouping is not feasible, say max 20 ID's will make one group in 900 million records hence this will be slow. hence in one batch i am taking 1 million records.